# Changing the order of concatenation of stylus files in Brunch

Tags: backbone.js, stylus, brunch

I have Brunch compiling Stylus for a Backbone.js app and I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the order. I've read [the documentation](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#files), but I haven't been able to get any further. The files always get concatenated in alphabetical order, and what's worse, if I use an `@import` command in a given stylus file, that file will get concatenated both where I've added it as well as where it would appear alphabetically.

My config.coffee file looks like this:

```
stylesheets:
  joinTo:
    'assets/stylesheets/app.css'
  order:
    before: [
      'vendor/styles/bootstrap.less'
    ]
    after: [ 
      'vendor/styles/helpers.css'
    ]
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|__details.styl
|__footer.styl
|__global.styl
|__header.styl
```

How can I

1. Omit certain files that I'm manually importing?
2. Specify my file order, e.g. global, details, header, footer?

I've tried to change the order in the config file by trying

```
  order:
    before: [
      'app/styles/global'
      'vendor/styles/bootstrap.less'
    ]
```

but this yielded no change.

I know I could just rename the files to be something like `a_global` and `z_footer`, but that's obviously hacky and it also doesn't solve my file omission problem. I'd also like to take advantage of the [stylus index import](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/import.html) ability so I can better organize my styles. However, if I were to do that now, while it works from a stylus perspective, those files are also getting concatenated to app.css in the alphabetical order of their parent directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that start with `_` are ignored by compilers.

Which means, you can do

```
@import _first
@import _second
@import _third
```

in your main stylus file and `_first` etc will be added only once to result.